# Expo AuthSession alternative

Tags: react-native, expo

After eject expo, AuthSession doesn't work (because is not supported in bare workflow yet). Which is the alternative of this library for a pure react-native application?

Answer (score 1):

If you have made `Expo` a stand-alone app, you should set it up further.

**Usage in standalone apps**

In order to be able to deep link back into your app, you will need to set a `scheme` in your project `app.json`, and then build your standalone app (it can't be updated with an OTA update). If you do not include a `scheme`, the authentication flow will complete but it will be unable to pass the information back into your application and the user will have to manually exit the authentication modal.

Comment: @VeljkoSimic  If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?